# How to transform a text into an array in lua

Tags: arrays, text, lua

Hey i'm trying to transform a text file into an array,

```
tutorial:gf
bopeebo:dad
fresh:dad
dadbattle:dad
spookeez:spooky
```

Result:

```
songs=['tutorial','bopeebo','fresh','dadbattle','spokeez']
characters=['gf','dad','dad','dad','spooky']
```

Comment: What have you tried? and what is not working with the attempted solution? also a table definition in Lua is done using `{` not `[`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to use [`io.lines(filename)`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-io.lines) to loop over the lines, using [`string.match`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.match) to extract each k-v pair:

```lua
local songs, characters = {}, {}
for line in io.lines(filename) do
    -- Uses .* to allow empty keys and values; use .+ instead to disallow
    local song, character = line:match"(.*):(.*)"
    table.insert(songs, song)
    table.insert(characters, character)
end
```

I would however question whether two lists are the right data structure for the job. You'll probably want to leverage the hash part of the table instead:

```lua
local character_by_song = {}
for line in io.lines(filename) do
    local song, character = line:match"(.*):(.*)"
    character_by_song[song] = character
end
```

This would allow you to look up which character is assigned to a specific song very efficiently (in constant time).